# Conditional Comments IE 11 Behavior

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, conditional-comments

I'm trying to build a simple conditional comment to check if the user has anything less than the IE9... 
Tried this just to debug the conditions, inside the body:

```
<!--[if !(IE)]>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">alert("NOT IE");</SCRIPT>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">alert("IE <9");</SCRIPT>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">alert("IE >=9");</SCRIPT>
<![endif]-->
```

When opening the page in IE or Firefox, nothing happen.

Then changed the comments format:

```
<!--[if !(IE)]>-->
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">alert("NOT IE");</SCRIPT>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>-->
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">alert("IE <9");</SCRIPT>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]>-->
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">alert("IE >=9");</SCRIPT>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

With this i get all the messages in both browsers?!?!

Then i take a look to the microsoft website, and found this sample:
http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/misc/ccdh02.htm

It works fine in both browsers directly from the link. So i just copied the source-code and pasted in a new page, and the code in the IE doesnt work (i can't tell if it really works in the Firefox, get the same results), it shows me this messages:
You are not using Internet Explorer.
You are using a downlevel browser.

So what's the problem? I replicated the entire page in a local file and the same thing happens...

I need to understand why this happen, or what i'm doing wrong, so then i can create my comment...

Thanks

Comment: This is not how you close a comment, it should be <![endif]-->

Comment: Also, you pretty much close the comment automatically, this is how ypu open one:  <!--[statement]>

Comment: Just testing this:[WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment)

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the microsoft sample code works "online" and not in a local file!?!